# Why does text command give warning while publishing strings in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

When i use the `text` command, it does do its work but gives a warning:

```
Warning: Error updating Text. Following is the chain of causes of the
error:

 String must have valid interpreter syntax:
^
```

The trouble is when i have to use the text command in a for loop 1000 times, the entire command window gets flooded with warnings which is sometimes inconvenient. I use the `text` command as follows.

```
figure();
set(gca,'YAxisLocation','Right','YDir','reverse')
axis([0 11 0 11]);
daspect([1,1,1])
rectangle('Position',[2,3,1,1])
text(5,6,'^');
view([-90 -90])
```

is there a work-around? I don't want the warning to be displayed. What is causing the warning?

EDIT:

Is there a way to put text in plot in matlab in any other way where this will not be encountered?

Comment: I don't seem to have this problem in Matlab R2014a.  What version of Matlab are you using?  Also, is this only happeneing when using a loop, or every time you use the `text` command?

Comment: what about using `text(5,6,'\^');` ?

Comment: @Benoit_11 Exactly, you said correctly, Benoit. I also figured that out right minutes after asking the question while tinkering for my own solution and have answered the same.

Comment: @CSCFCEM i made some edits and also the problem is resolved now. Refer to the answer or benoit's comment though Crazy rat's tip is also very handy.

Comment: Alright I guess you can accept your own answer then so that the thread is closed.

Comment: @Benoit_11 Thanks, I will do that in 2 days as per the rule of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters like ^,\, etc are interpreted in a pre-defined manner in Matlab hence pose difficulty. Use:
`text(5, 6, '\^');`

Answer (score 1):

Set the interpreter to "none". 
For example:

```
text(1,1,'c:\games\digger','interpreter','none')
```

This applies also for TITLE, XLABEL and other similar commands.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce you problem (Ubuntu, R2014b). However, to get rid of warning messages you can simply disable/enable the warnings around your problematic line:

```
warning off
text(5, 6, 'T');
warning on
```

Comment: I edited the `text` line, apologies, also i figured the error after tinkering a bit and have answered now.

Comment: Thanks for the off-on tip. It is sure to come very handy in future.